# C++ threaded application runs slower than non-threaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am currently writing a prime number generator in C++. I have made a single-threaded version first, and later a multi-threaded version.

I found out that if my program generates values less than `100'000`, the single-threaded version is faster than the multi-threaded one. Obviously I am doing something wrong.

My code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>

using namespace std;

set<unsigned long long> primeContainer;
shared_mutex m;

void checkPrime(const unsigned long long p)
{
    if (p % 3 == 0)
        return;

    bool isPrime = true;
    for (set<unsigned long long>::const_iterator it = primeContainer.cbegin(); it != primeContainer.cend(); ++it)
    {
        if (p % *it == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
        if (*it * *it > p) // check only up to square root
            break;
    }

    if (isPrime)
        primeContainer.insert(p);
}

void checkPrimeLock(const unsigned long long p)
{
    if (p % 3 == 0)
        return;

    bool isPrime = true;
    try
    {
        shared_lock<shared_mutex> l(m);
        for (set<unsigned long long>::const_iterator it = primeContainer.cbegin(); it != primeContainer.cend(); ++it)
        {
            if (p % *it == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
            if (*it * *it > p)
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    if (isPrime)
    {
        try
        {
            unique_lock<shared_mutex> l(m);
            primeContainer.insert(p);
        }
        catch (exception& e)
        {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
}

void runLoopThread(const unsigned long long& l)
{
    for (unsigned long long i = 10; i < l; i += 10)
    {
        thread t1(checkPrimeLock, i + 1);
        thread t2(checkPrimeLock, i + 3);
        thread t3(checkPrimeLock, i + 7);
        thread t4(checkPrimeLock, i + 9);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
    }
}

void runLoop(const unsigned long long& l)
{
    for (unsigned long long i = 10; i < l; i += 10)
    {
        checkPrime(i + 1);
        checkPrime(i + 3);
        checkPrime(i + 7);
        checkPrime(i + 9);
    }
}

void printPrimes(const unsigned long long& l)
{
    if (1U <= l)
        cout << "1 ";
    if (2U <= l)
        cout << "2 ";
    if (3U <= l)
        cout << "3 ";
    if (5U <= l)
        cout << "5 ";

    for (auto it = primeContainer.cbegin(); it != primeContainer.cend(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it <= l)
            cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void writeToFile(const unsigned long long& l)
{
    string name = "primes_" + to_string(l) + ".txt";
    ofstream f(name);

    if (f.is_open())
    {
        if (1U <= l)
            f << "1 ";
        if (2U <= l)
            f << "2 ";
        if (3U <= l)
            f << "3 ";
        if (5U <= l)
            f << "5 ";

        for (auto it = primeContainer.cbegin(); it != primeContainer.cend(); ++it)
        {
            if (*it <= l)
                f << *it << " ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file." << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int n = thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::cout << n << " concurrent threads are supported." << endl;

    unsigned long long limit;
    cout << "Please enter the limit of prime generation: ";
    cin >> limit;

    primeContainer.insert(7);

    if (10 < limit)
    {
        //runLoop(limit); //single-threaded
        runLoopThread(limit); //multi-threaded
    }

    printPrimes(limit);
    //writeToFile(limit);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In the `main` function you will find comments about which function is single and multi threaded.

The main difference between those is the use of locks, shared for container iteration, and unique for insertion. If it matters, my CPU has 4 cores.

Why is the single thread version faster?

Comment: multithreading is never guaranteed to be faster and is often slower, especially when there are locks which can turn code back into synchronous behaviour if you're not careful.

Comment: I think that this is due to the overhead of creating the threads. The time it takes to start each thread and shut them back down is much larger than the time which is saved by doing the computations in parallel. Rather than creating a thread to check a single number, you could make that same thread check every number ending in a 1, or a 3, etc. However, in this case, you would have to adjust your primality test to deal with the threads acting at different rates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it seems you are starting a new thread for each single prime number check. That is not good IMHO, because the thread startup/shutdown plus the synchronization adds to calculation of each prime. Starting a thread can be quite slow.

I would recommend to start those 4 threads outside of the main `for` loop and process 1/4 of the range in each thread. But this might need some additional synchronization, because to check a prime, the code above apparently needs to first have primes up to sqrt N available.

From my point of view, it might be easier to use the [Sieve of Erastothenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm, which might be much easier to parallelize without any locking (however might still suffer the problem known as "[false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)").

**EDIT**

Here I quickly created a version using the Sieve of Erastothenes:

```
void processSieve(const unsigned long long& l,
    const unsigned long long& start,
    const unsigned long long& end,
    const unsigned long long& step,
    vector<char> &is_prime)
{
    for (unsigned long long i = start; i <= end; i += step)
        if (is_prime[i])
            for (unsigned long long j = i + i; j <= l; j += i)
                is_prime[j] = 0;
}

void runSieve(const unsigned long long& l)
{
    vector<char> is_prime(l + 1, 1);
    unsigned long long end = sqrt(l);
    processSieve(l, 2, end, 1, is_prime);
    primeContainer.clear();
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= l; ++i)
        if (is_prime[i])
            primeContainer.insert(i);
}

void runSieveThreads(const unsigned long long& l)
{
    vector<char> is_prime(l + 1, 1);
    unsigned long long end = sqrt(l);
    vector<thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(cpuCount);
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < cpuCount; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back(processSieve, l, 2 + i, end, cpuCount, ref(is_prime));
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < cpuCount; ++i)
        threads[i].join();
    primeContainer.clear();
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= l; ++i)
        if (is_prime[i])
            primeContainer.insert(i);
}
```

The measurement results, primes up to 1 000 000 (MSVC 2013, Release):

```
runLoop: 204.02 ms
runLoopThread: 43947.4 ms
runSieve: 30.003 ms
runSieveThreads (8 cores): 24.0024 ms
```

Up to 10 0000 000:

```
runLoop: 4387.44 ms
// runLoopThread disabled, taking too long
runSieve: 350.035 ms
runSieveThreads (8 cores): 285.029 ms
```

The times include final processing of the vector and pushing the results to the prime set.

As you can see, the Sieve version is much faster than your version even in single threaded version (for your mutex version I had to change the lock to regular mutex locks because the MSVC 2013 does not have shared_lock, so the results are likely much worse than yours).

But you can see that the multithreaded version of the sieve still does not run as fast as expected (8 cores, i.e. 8 threads, linear speedup would be 8x faster than single thread), although there is no locking (trading off that some numbers might run unnecessarily if they were not marked as "no primes" by the other threads yet, but in general the results should be stable, because only set to 0 every time, does not matter if set simultaneously by multiple threads). The cause why the speedup is not linear is most likely because of the "[false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)" problem as I mentioned before - the threads writing the zeros invalidate each other cache lines.

Answer (score 10):

You have several problems.

First, you keep creating and destroying threads needlessly. Have each thread loop doing work until there is no more work to do.

Second, your locks are *way* too fine and as a result, you're acquiring them *way* too often. Have each thread grab a block of 100 numbers to test rather than one at a time, and have them insert found primes from each block in one go.

Comment: +1 You can completely avoid locking by having your threads check disjoint sets of numbers and each writing to their own container. When the threads are done, simply concatenate all containers.

Comment: It's not as simple as "threads make things go faster". A lot of things can be made faster with threads, but it's not simple to do it well enough to get a significant performance boost. Ironically, it's a lot harder in "toy" code like this than it is in real code.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions, I made a few improvements: each thread now processes values ending in 1, 3, 7 and 9, respectively. That solves your first point. For your second point, I am still trying to think of something. I like @denniskb suggestion, since I never reach the end of the container right now, only the first half of it. I could keep a local set for each thread, insert the newfound primes into those local sets, and when I reach the end of the main set in some thread, signal the threads to dump their local sets into the main set. Though, it sounds like more lock use. Dunno :/

Comment: @S.T.A.L.K.E.R. actually, my approach wouldn't require any locking whatsoever. I posted an example in the form of an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Since the comment section was getting a bit crowded and OP expressed interest in a lockless solution, I'm providing an example of such an approach below (in semi-pseudocode):

```
vector<uint64_t> primes_thread1;
vector<uint64_t> primes_thread2;
...

// check all numbers in [start, end)
void check_primes(uint64_t start, uint64_t end, vector<uint64_t> & out) {
    for (auto i = start; i < end; ++i) {
        if (is_prime(i)) { // simply loop through all odds from 3 to sqrt(i)
            out.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}

auto f1 = async(check_primes, 1, 1000'000, ref(primes_thread1));
auto f2 = async(check_primes, 1000'000, 2000'000, ref(primes_thread2));
...

f1.wait();
f2.wait();
...

primes_thread1.insert(
    primes_thread1.begin(),
    primes_thread2.cbegin(), primes_thread2.cend()
);
primes_thread1.insert(
    primes_thread1.begin(),
    primes_thread3.cbegin(), primes_thread3.cend()
);
...
// primes_thread1 contains all primes found in all threads
```

Obviously this can be refactored nicely by parameterizing the number of threads and the size of each range. I was being verbose to (hopefully) more clearly illustrate the concept of avoiding locking by not sharing any state in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There might be another problem in your prime test. You are never testing against 7 as divisor.

Further more, your test assumes that primeContainer already holds all prime numbers between 10 and the sqare root of the number being tested. That might be not the case if you use threads to fill the container.

If you fill the container with always increasing numbers (and your algorithm counts on that), you could use std::vector instead of std::set for better performance.